# XAML Parse Exception in Windows 8 C# metro style app

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, microsoft-metro

I am running Visual Studio 2012 SP1 and I am creating a Windows 8 C#  Metro style app and I keep getting an error on "InitializeComponent()"

The error I receive is an "XamlParseException" and the detailed information is 
"XAML parsing failed."

The XAML for the page looks fine and is showing no errors.

Could it be something to do with SP1 (as prior to SP1 it was building OK).

Any help appreciated.
Regards
Mark

Comment: In such cases I'm just commenting out parts of code until the bug is nailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether it's your issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773691/windowsstore-xamlparseexception-after-vs2012-update-1
If it is, the workaround is to rename either assembly or namespace so that they are the same.

Comment: Hey, seems to be likely just looking into it now. Will let you know either way.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a problem in your XAML. The exception detail usually contains the exact problem or at least the line number with the problem in your XAML. Check it out.

Comment: It is stating an assembly is missing for a custom name space. even though it is the same that was working before the SP1 update. Def seems to be what notacat suggested.